# ALTER TABLE syntax - missing DIRECTORY keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to alter a table in Oracle database by adding two new columns to it with SQL query as below:

```
ALTER TABLE Members 
      ADD annual_dues NUMBER(5,2) not null DEFAULT '52.50', 
      ADD payment_date DATE;
```

On executing it, I am getting an error as below:

> SQL Error: ORA-30649: missing DIRECTORY keyword

I have played around it but it didn't help. What is wrong in the SQL query?

Comment: Is this for Oracle or for MySQL ?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#CJAHHIBI

Comment: The errors you showed are from Oracle DBMS, not from MySQL.

Comment: Updated link to docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2103924

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think you need to put `NOT NULL` after the `DEFAULT 52.50`:

```
ALTER TABLE Members 
   ADD ( annual_dues NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT 52.50 NOT NULL
       , payment_date DATE );
```

Comment: @ypercubeIt worked. It seems like the order of attributes made the difference.Thanks

Comment: Please edit the tag of the question. You clearly have Oracle, no matter what application you are using to connect to it.

Comment: Whatever the course is named, the error message ***"SQL Error: ORA-30649: missing DIRECTORY keyword"*** has an **"ORA-"** which is a clear indication that the DBMS you are connected to is Oracle. Plus, the syntax for `ALTER TABLE` differs slightly between the two.